# Codeigniter: Variables/Config Items within Language Files

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, config

I have a language file with a long list of strings for my view files.
My question is how to pass a variable or a config item to a language file?

```
<?php $lang['error_activation_key_expired'] = 'The activation key you have attempted using has expired. Please request a new Activation Key <a href="'.$this->config->item('base_url').'member/request_activation" title="Request a New Activation Key">here</a>.';
```

I would could settle for

```
<?php $lang['error_activation_key_expired'] = 'The activation key you have attempted using has expired. Please request a new Activation Key <a href="'.$base_url.'member/request_activation" title="Request a New Activation Key">here</a>.';
```

and pass the base_url to it somehow. I just don't know how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to put a placeholder in there, then swap it out in your controller.

Lang file:

```
<?php $lang['error_activation_key_expired'] = 'The activation key you have attempted using has expired. Please request a new Activation Key <a href="%s/member/request_activation" title="Request a New Activation Key">here</a>.';
```

In controller:

```
$activation_message = sprintf($this->lang->line('error_activation_key_expired'), $base_url);
```

Comment: I reference the base_url multiple times throughout that language file. Will there be an issue with repetition?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Repetition where?

Answer (score 5):

In CI Forum, [nlogachev](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/145634/#745143) suggest better solution. 
It can switch variables order.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Language extends CI_Language
{

    function MY_Language()
    {
        parent::CI_Language();
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a single line of text from the language array. Takes variable number
     * of arguments and supports wildcards in the form of '%1', '%2', etc.
     * Overloaded function.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return mixed false if not found or the language string
     */
    public function line()
    {
        //get the arguments passed to the function
        $args = func_get_args();

        //count the number of arguments
        $c = count($args);

        //if one or more arguments, perform the necessary processing
        if ($c)
        {
            //first argument should be the actual language line key
            //so remove it from the array (pop from front)
            $line = array_shift($args);

            //check to make sure the key is valid and load the line
            $line = ($line == '' OR ! isset($this->language[$line])) ? FALSE : $this->language[$line];

            //if the line exists and more function arguments remain
            //perform wildcard replacements
            if ($line && $args)
            {
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($args as $arg)
                {
                    $line = preg_replace('/\%'.$i.'/', $arg, $line);
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if no arguments given, no language line available
            $line = false;
        }

        return $line;
    }


}

?>
```

use case~

```
//in english
$lang['some_key'] = 'Some string with %1 %2.';

//in another language
$lang['some_key'] = 'Some string %2 with %1.';

//the actual usage
echo $this->lang->line('some_key','first','second');
```

Comment: Perfect answer. In my opinion, your answer had to be accepted.