# How to return variable values in codeigniter language line strings?

Tags: codeigniter-2, multilingual

To be more clear, none of these lines in default language's `general_lang.php` work:

```
$lang['general_welcome_message'] = 'Welcome, %s ( %s )';
```

or

```
$lang['general_welcome_message'] = 'Welcome, %1 ( %2 )';
```

I expect an output like **`Welcome, FirstName ( user_name )`**.

I followed the second **(not accepted)** answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973668/315550.

The code I write in the view is:

```
<div id="welcome-box">
    <?php echo lang('general_welcome_message',
               $this->session->userdata('user_firstname'),
               $this->session->userdata('username')
               );
    ?>
</div>
```

I use codeigniter 2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to use php's sprintf function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Example from http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/145634/#749634:

```
//in english
$lang['unread_messages'] = "You have %1$s unread messages, %2$s";

//in another language
$lang['unread_messages'] = "Hi %2$s, You have %1$s unread messages";

$message = sprintf($this->lang->line(‘unread_messages’), $number, $name);
```

Answer (score 2):

I extended Code CI_Lang class like this..

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {
    function line($line = '', $swap = null) {
        $loaded_line    = parent::line($line);
        // If swap if not given, just return the line from the language file (default codeigniter functionality.)
        if(!$swap) return $loaded_line;

        // If an array is given
        if (is_array($swap)) {
            // Explode on '%s'
            $exploded_line = explode('%s', $loaded_line);

            // Loop through each exploded line
            foreach ($exploded_line as $key => $value) {
                // Check if the $swap is set
                if(isset($swap[$key])) {
                    // Append the swap variables
                    $exploded_line[$key] .= $swap[$key];
                }
            }
            // Return the implode of $exploded_line with appended swap variables
            return implode('', $exploded_line);
        }
        // A string is given, just do a simple str_replace on the loaded line
        else {
            return str_replace('%s', $swap, $loaded_line);
        }
    }
}
```

ie. In your language file:

```
$lang['foo'] = 'Thanks, %s. Your %s has been changed.'
```

And where-ever you want to use it (controller / view etc.)

```
echo $this->lang->line('foo', array('Charlie', 'password'));
```

Will produce

```
Thanks, Charlie. Your password has been changed.
```

This handles single 'swaps' as well as multiple

Also it won't break any existing calls to `$this->lang->line`.

Comment: Very neat. Thanks !